# How do I extract a number from a text file and perform modular arithmetic?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi this is from a newbie programmer using python so bear with me.  I'm trying make use of the mod function in python '%' to extract factors from a formula 2^p-1 when 'p' is prime and the formula 2^p-1 produces a factor.

For instance when p=11 2^p-1=2047 so the first factor if using modular '%' would be 23.  Factors in general when 'p' is prime and using 2^p-1 are prime themselves.

My question is if I use a large text file loaded with prime numbers, is it possible to quickly access a number and perform a modular arithmetic using it to find a factor for 2^p-1?  My code that I have is poor and it throws an error, can anyone correct it for me?  Here is my code in python 3.7!

This is my text file k.txt:

k=(3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23, 47, 223, 233)

This is my error:

> File "Factor This.py", line 6, in  if (2**p-1) %
> (open("C:\python37\k.txt"),'r') == 0: TypeError: unsupported operand
> type(s) for %: 'int' and 'tuple'

```
 import timeit
 while True:
     p = int(input("Enter a prime number: "))
     start_time = timeit.default_timer()
     for k in range(3,300,2):
         if (2**p-1) % (open("C:\python37\k.txt"),'r') == 0:
             print(k)
             print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time,'seconds')
             break
```

Comment: `(open("C:\python37\k.txt"),'r')` is a tuple with 2 elements. Put 'r' in `open` function parameter.

Comment: Joonyoung Park, thanks I'm new can you show me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple method should work:

```py
p = int(input("Enter a prime number: "))

with open("C:\python37\k.txt",'r') as f:
    primes = f.read().split("(")[1].split(')')[0].split(',')  # int list of primes
    primes = [int(i.strip()) for i in primes]
    for prime in primes:
        if (2**p - 1) % int(prime) == 0:
            print(prime)
            break
```

Comment: Hi Abhinav Mathur, well this error came back:                        
                                                                                     
        Enter a prime number: 23
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Factor mod fast txt.py", line 5, in <module>
    primes = [int(i.strip()) for i in primes]
  File "Factor mod fast txt.py", line 5, in <listcomp>
    primes = [int(i.strip()) for i in primes]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(3'

Comment: Okay, modified the answer

Comment: Thanks so much Abhinav Mathur this has helped me a great deal in the hunt for Mersenne Prime numbers, now I hope for greater speed we shall see :)